# Update trajectory path on a Google Maps trajectory plugin

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am using the Google Maps javascript application and I would like to update a trajectoryPath I have drawn on the map with a user button press. Currently I have it set to just call initialize() and reload the whole map to update the trajectory lines but I would like the paths to be updated without having to reload the whole map (to cut down on rendering time) and just plot the lines upon the user action.